# Possible forms of open balls

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider $X=  ( \Bbb Q \cap [ 0,3] , d_E)$The question is as such:

"Describe the possible forms that an open ball can take in $X = (\Bbb Q ∩ [0, 3], d_E )$."

I don't understand this means exactly. Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

Comment: What does $d_E$ mean?

Comment: Is $X$ considered as a general topological space with a general metric?

Comment: @Student The euclidean metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open unit ball around $0$ in the Euclidean metric is $B_1(0)=\{x\in X:|x|<1\}$. Any open ball in that metric is $B_r(y)=\{x\in X:|x-y|<r\}$.

The shape of a ball is either disjoint points on the the real line which are dense in some interval if the ball is disjoint from $[0,3]$, a whole interval if the ball is contained in $[0,3]$, or a mix of those when the ball intersects with $[0,3]$ but is not contained in it.

Comment: I there any simpler way to represent this?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean in mathematical symbols?

Comment: Yep, I mean symbols

Comment: Yes, a ball in $X$, $B^X_r(x)$ equals the intersection of a ball in $\mathbb R$ with $X$. That is $B^X_r(x)=B^{\mathbb R}_r(x)\cap X$. Here we are considering the Eucledian metric on the real line. With an upper index I am indicating where the ball is. Also implicitly I am considering the natural inclusion $X\subset\mathbb R$.